# Random number generator always returning 0 when given a range

Tags: java, random

I'm making a guessing game where the user sets the maximum number and that number is used for the range for the random number generator, but every time I test my program it outputs 0. I'm not sure why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {

public static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
public static Random random = new Random();

public static int answer;  
public static int maxNumber;  
public static int minNumber = 0;              

public static void main (String [] args ){                     
                            
  System.out.println("Welcome to the Guessing Game.");
  System.out.println("Enter the maximum number.");
  int maxNumber = scan.nextInt(); 
  System.out.println(answer); //Remove after testing 
} 
 public static int newGame(Random random) {  
  int randNumber;
  int range = maxNumber - minNumber; 
  randNumber = random.nextInt(range);                                 
  answer = randNumber;     
     return answer;     
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `newGame`? Therefore, `answer` is uninitialized.

Comment: My professor told us to have answer as an instance variable to avoid method calls. Should I use a method call in this case?

Comment: __ have answer as an instance variable to avoid method calls.__ <-- this statement makes no sense. Your prof did not say this; you misheard her.

Comment: He explicitly said that we won't need a method call because of instance variables. He even put that in the instructions for the project. I'm starting to question everything my professor taught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call the `public static int newGame(Random random)` function. In java the default value of an integer is 0.

You did not call the function, so it did not change the value of `answer`.

Also if you don't want an extra method for this you can use the following:

```
public static void main (String [] args ){                     
                            
  System.out.println("Welcome to the Guessing Game.");
  System.out.println("Enter the maximum number.");
  int maxNumber = scan.nextInt(); 
  answer = new Random().nextInt(maxNumber - minNumber);
  System.out.println(answer); //Remove after testing 
}
```

Or if you want to use the method:

```
public static void main (String [] args ){                     
                            
  System.out.println("Welcome to the Guessing Game.");
  System.out.println("Enter the maximum number.");
  maxNumber = scan.nextInt(); 
  answer = newGame(random);
  System.out.println(answer); //Remove after testing 
} 

public static int newGame(Random random) {  
  int range = maxNumber - minNumber; 
  return random.nextInt(range);      
}
```

Comment: I tried the second option because I need the newGame method for my project and it gave me an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive

Comment: I changed the code. Change the `int maxNumber = scan.nextInt(); ` to `maxNumber = scan.nextInt(); `. Because of the `int` keyword a new variable created and set the value of it. So the class variable `maxNumber` stayed default value (0)

Or you can pass this `int maxNumber = scan.nextInt()` variable to the newGame if you add a `int maxNumber` parameter after `Random random`

Comment: That mostly fixed it but in the main method there's an error: cannot find symbol answer = newGame(random);. Not sure how it can't find it when it's calling the other method.

Comment: Well, either copy the `answer` variable from your code or just put the word `int` before it. (`int answer = ...`)

Comment: Saved it and restarted my laptop and it worked just fine. Thank you for your help (:

Answer (score 0):

You have NOT called the function `newGame` in `main`!
You may have to do this in `main`:

```
System.out.println(newGame(random));
```

OR:

```
answer = newGame(random);
System.out.println(answer);
```

You may want to look at this function:

```
public static int randNum(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int val = Math.abs(rand.nextInt());
        val = (val % (max - min + 1)) + min;
        
        return val;
    }
```

This function is to randomize a non-negative number between `min` and `max`. You can let it `min = 0` or just eliminate `min` from the formula if you just need any non-negative number.

Comment: this won't fix OP's problem

Comment: I added some more.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after `scan.nextInt()`:

```
answer = newGame(random);
```

---

Also, there's a bug in your `newGame` method. Change:

```
answer = randNumber;
```

to

```
answer = randNumber + minNumber;
```

Comment: Adding a scanner and inputting a number defeats the purpose of guessing the number.

Comment: @DarthVaderBarbie There is no scanner added. I don't know why you would think that from my answer. The only change I suggested  is adding `answer = newGame(random);`. And none of the other answers seems to have noticed the bug in your newGame method.

Comment: I apologize, at that point my brain was fried and the first thing I saw was the scanner. It's technically not a bug since the minNumber is zero. It's fine without subtracting it. Again, I apologize for my misunderstanding.